# Implementing a sorting key in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We store relationships between documents in an Oracle db using a table having a column named docid and a column named parentid. If I have a document, doc1, related to child documents, child1_1 and child1_2 they would be represented by the following records in the Documents table.

```
docid  parentid
1000   null    record for doc1
1001   1000    "       "  child1_1
1002   1000    "       "  child1_2
```

The Documents table can have millions of rows, so to make sure all related documents are grouped together in our UI we pre-sort the Documents table by using an indexed varchar column named sortedfamily and populate it with the concatenation of the docids of the related documents. Without using the sortedfamily column sorting the records at query time is too slow. The records shown above become.

```
docid  parentid  sortedfamily
1000   null      1000           record for doc1
1001   1000      1000_1001      "       "  child1_1
1002   1000      1000_1002      "       "  child1_2
```

This allows us to add 'ordered by sortedfamily' to our queries and the returned records will always be sorted by related documents. What I outlined above works pretty well but it has some limitations related to a document family hierarchical depth and it feels weird concatenating integers to sort the records. Is there a way to do the above using only integers?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: My example above was not detailed enough. The children themselves may also have related documents. If child1_1 had a related document the resulting value for sortedfamily may be "1000_1001_2000".

Comment: What if sort by parentid first,then  by docid. Order by COALESCE(parentid,docid),docid

Comment: The Documents table can have millions of rows in it and we have found that without a column containing the sort key the performance is sub-par.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle has excellent support for hierarchical queries. You can get your document hierarchy without resorting to the `sortedfamily` column. Here's the query:

```
SELECT docid, PRIOR docid AS "Parent"
FROM Documents
START WITH parentid IS NULL
CONNECT BY parentid = PRIOR docid
ORDER SIBLINGS BY docid
```

Now to explain:

```
SELECT docid, PRIOR docid AS "Parent"
```

This gets the document and its parent on the same row by "looking back" with the `PRIOR` operator.

```
START WITH parentid IS NULL
```

This defines the hierarchy's root. Every row that has a null `parentid` is considered the root of a branch.

```
CONNECT BY parentid = PRIOR docid
```

This says that the "parent" of the current row is connected by `parentid` of the child up to `docid` of the parent.

```
ORDER SIBLINGS BY docid
```

This sorts along the entire hierarchy rather than a single value. It's hard to explain, but it works.

The best thing about the Oracle hierarchical queries is that they'll query an entire branch, so if you have a document with a child that has a child (that has a child, and on on...) Oracle will handle it. It will also handle multiple children per parent.

There's a [SQL Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a4e84/1) with your data plus a few additional documents.

The Fiddle also includes a column that shows the entire "root to branch" relationship using the `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` function. The `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` does the same thing as your `sortedfamily` column, but it does it dynamically, without the need to maintain the column. It's also a good way to visualize each branch of the hierarchy.

**Addendum**

Note that the query above will return *every* branch for *every* document. If you're just interested in a single document such as `docid = 1000`, replace the `START WITH parentid IS NULL` with this:

```
START WITH docid = 1000
```

That will give you the entire branch for `docid` 1000. If you have an index on `docid` it will be very fast.

Comment: Thanks Ed for the detailed solution. Can you take a look at the edit I made to the OP and indicated if this would change your solution? Our Documents table typically has tens of millions of rows. Is your solution feasible in that context?

Comment: The solution will work if the child documents have children. Oracle will find the entire branch. To see it in action, go to the Fiddle (there's a link to it above) and change `START WITH parentid IS NULL` to `START WITH docid = 4000`. The Fiddle data sets up `docid 4000` to have multiple levels of children.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any comment about if this technique is feasible in the context of tens of millions of rows?

Comment: If you're selecting hierarchies for specific documents (`START WITH docid = nnn`) it'll be super-fast as long as you have an index on the `docid` column. With so many rows you probably do anyway. You can add `WHERE` logic to this type of query as well, and its speed will depend on how optimizable the `WHERE` logic is, just as it would with a "regular" non-hierarchical query. I'd suggest giving it a try against your existing data - just **don't run the query with** `START WITH parentid IS NULL` because that will query *everything*, and that'll be slow no matter how you do it.

Comment: This is incredibly powerful. I had no idea it existed, thank you Ed!
For others, FYI, the SqlFiddle uses Oracle 11g, but per these docs 10g has it as well.
http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/queries003.htm